# Can i get the profit of viewed reward ad

Tags: admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

Can i get the current profit value after viewing the reward ad of admob ?

Is the reward ad allowed only for games category  ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The short answer is below:

Can I get the current profit value after viewing the reward ad of Admob? --No, you can not.

Is the reward ad allowed only for games category? -- You can use a reward ad on non-gaming app.

### Advanced for your first question

If we are not able to know how much benefit we can get from Admob by each reward video ad impression, then how can we know how much we should reward the end-user to watch a video ad?
The short answer again is that you have to try the ad-network like Admob and decide the reward amount by yourself.

Below are some reasons:

1. Most ads from Admob and other ad networks like Vungle, MoPub, UnityAds, and IronSource are mainly based on the CPI model so far. They(Ad-Networks) do not even know if the end-user would install an app from reward app or not. But even they know they would not let the publisher know the price base on the CPI model. Cause the advertisers are looking for users who like their game. The advertisers are not looking for users just for your game's reward to install their app. You can expect the [header bidding](https://digiday.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Twitter_MoPub_Digiday_WTF-is-header-bidding-mobile-apps.pdf) which is still developing at the mobile Ad-network industry.
2. eCPM in different regions will be quite different. Ideally, the US, EU have higher eCPM than other regions. Then you might need to give them a higher amount reward after they watched a reward video ad from your app. ([eCPM](https://www.marketingterms.com/dictionary/ecpm/) = (Total Earnings / Impressions) x 1000, CPI = Cost per install)

### Reference:

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7372450?hl=en
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7313578?hl=en